# My span tag inside li tag is not getting aligned properly even though height of span and li tag is same

Tags: html, css

you  can see from the images that there is nothing conflicting to put the icon at that position. it should be naturally be aligned with li tag since both li and span tag height is same. 
I tried other people who did the same project from a udemy course. I copy pasted their css file in my css. guess what it appears the same way.

This is a todo list I am working on. I am a beginner.

```css
body {
    background: #03001e;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdeff9, #ec38bc, #7303c0, #03001e);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdeff9, #ec38bc, #7303c0, #03001e); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    
}
h1 {
    background: #2980b9;
    color:white;
    margin:0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 20px;
   font-size: 24px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.fa-pencil-alt
{
    float:right;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container {
     border: solid 2px gray;
     width:380px; 
     margin: 100px auto;
     background:#f7f7f7;
     box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.completed {
    color:gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

body {font-family:Roboto;}
li{

    background:white;
    height:40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color:#666;
}
li:nth-child(2n)
{
    background:#f7f7f7;
}
input {
    font-size:18px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    width:100%;
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#2980b9;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
input:focus {
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px solid  #2980b9;
    outline: none;
}

span {
    background:#e74c3c;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right:20px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
   width:40px; 
    display: inline-block;
    transition:0.2s linear; 
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

````html
```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/1.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8706ae3761.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<div id="container">
    <h1>Todo List <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todos">
    <ul>
        <li><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>  </span> Homework</li>
        <li><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>  </span> Exercise</li>
        <li><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>  </span> Gaming</li>
        <li><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>  </span> Dinner</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="sandbox.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
````

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try using flexbox?

Comment: It looks good here: https://jsfiddle.net/jwrgks06/  What browser are you using?

Comment: It's not clear what "aligned properly" means. Your screenshots look great. If anything, it's the use of margin rather than padding.

Comment: I am using chrome

Answer (score 0):

Remove height and line-height from li tag and manage with top/bottom padding of span

```css
body {
    background: #03001e;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdeff9, #ec38bc, #7303c0, #03001e);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdeff9, #ec38bc, #7303c0, #03001e); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}
h1 {
    background: #2980b9;
    color:white;
    margin:0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 20px;
   font-size: 24px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.fa-pencil-alt
{
    float:right;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container {
     border: solid 2px gray;
     width:380px; 
     margin: 100px auto;
     background:#f7f7f7;
     box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.completed {
    color:gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

body {font-family:Roboto;}
li{

    background:white;
    color:#666;
    /* height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;*/
}
li:nth-child(2n)
{
    background:#f7f7f7;
}
input {
    font-size:18px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    width:100%;
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#2980b9;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
input:focus {
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px solid  #2980b9;
    outline: none;
}

span {
    background:#e74c3c;
    /*height: 40px;*/
    margin-right:20px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
   width:40px; 
    display: inline-block;
    transition:0.2s linear; 
    opacity:1.0;
    padding:15px 0px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/1.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8706ae3761.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Todo List <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todos">
    <ul>
        <li><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>  </span> Homework</li>
        <li><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>  </span> Exercise</li>
        <li><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>  </span> Gaming</li>
        <li><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>  </span> Dinner</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="sandbox.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```